# Sata ports 1 and2 damaged is there a workaround?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I decided to blow the cobwebs off my old pc however whilst putting a graphics card back in i damage sata ports 1&2, I then tried connecting the 2xhdd to ports 3&4 but they only come up as slaves in the bios, is there a workaround this or do I need a new motherboard?

Specs:

```
abit aw9d max
core 2 quad 2.4ghz
6gb ddr2
2x8800gtx
2x 250gb sata hdd
```

Comment: Does the motherboard have problems actually _using_ these disks?

Answer (score 1):

SATA doesn't even have a concept of 'master/slave' ports – this was specific to Parallel ATA (IDE), which did share a single port between two devices.

The only reason I can imagine they show up for SATA devices is because your firmware is set to "IDE"/"RAID"/"compatibility" mode (PATA emulation), as opposed to "AHCI" (which is the native SATA mode), and so it *pretends* that the four SATA ports are still legacy PATA ports.

(But even in actual PATA, this distinction did not affect much in terms of daily usage, and I don't think I've seen a recent BIOS that would prevent a PATA 'slave' disk from being used as the OS/boot disk either.)

If the system works in this configuration, I would just ignore the weird labelling.

Comment: this pc has not been switched on for probably a decade until i bought a new psu for it, when opened in bios it shows the 2 sata hdd as ide slaves 3 & 4,

Comment: if i continue the boot it says boot error please load system disk and press enter